# Recursion only works when using breakpoints or getchar

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

I've been trying to implement a function that will auto-generate a random binary tree depending on the number of nodes that receives as a parameter. Whenever I run my code, it executes once and it exits normally, no matter the number of nodes that I specify.
Here's my code:

```
struct Node
{
    int number;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};

void insert(Node** node, int numberOfNodes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        int randomNumber = rand() % 36;
        if (!insertNumber(node, randomNumber))
        {
            i--;
        }
        //getchar();
        //If I don't use this getchar() 
        //or execute with breakpoints, it only inserts one node.
    }
}

bool insertNumber(Node** node, int number)
{
    Node* newNode = NULL;
    if (*node == NULL)
    {
        newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;
        newNode->number = number;
        *node = newNode;
        return true;
    }
    else if (number < (*node)->number)
    {
        insertNumber(&(*node)->left, number);
        return true;
    }
    else if (number > (*node)->number)
    {
        insertNumber(&(*node)->right, number);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    //if equal, do not insert
}
```

This is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Node* root = NULL;

    int numberOfNodes = 10;

    printf("Starting test\n");

    insert(&root, numberOfNodes);

    printAllLevels(root);

    printf("program finished\n");
}
```

So the program finishes before the recursion, and only one node is displayed. I tried using sleep(), but it didn't help at all.

Can you help me figure out what my code is missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
insertNumber(&(*node)->left, number);
return true;
```

You should have `return insertNumber(&(*node)->left, number);`

Notice that because of this bug you are returning `true` even when you don't add a node to the tree. Therefore your check

```
if (!insertNumber(node, randomNumber))
{
    i--;
}
```

Doesn't decrement `i` and your loop continues thinking it added the node.

Next your `srand` should only happen once, outside the loop. Because `time(NULL)` returns the number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970, your code is seeding the random number generator with the same value over and over (until the next second elapses... which is a rare occurrence inside that tight loop). So your code tries to add the same number over and over again to the tree. This bug, combined with your previous bug gives your observed behavior.

When you add breakpoints or pause for user input with `getchar` you are causing a timing delay and, if the delay is long enough, the random number generator will get seeded with a different value and a new node may be added to the tree.

Comment: *"Next your srand should only happen once, outside the loop*" in `main()`. (`insert` can be called more than once changing the *random seed*)

Comment: Thank you very much @MFisherKDX! It actually works this time. I had been dealing with this for a while and didn't catch it, I still have lots to learn.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin As you said, it could be called multiple times but for this first exercise, only once will suffice. I'll still take into account that if i wanted to run it multiple times, the current location of srand() could work. Thank you.

Comment: @Shaiduck More importantly, if you want to run it multiple times the current location of `srand()` could fail.  You really should move it to `main()`.